# Event when app is removed from background or deleted in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

I want to take some action when user deletes the app and removes the app from background.

Is there any event of UIApplication class that gets called or any alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Removes the app from the background: `applicationWillTerminate` in your app delegate.

Deletes the app - not that I know of.

Comment: THanks a lot it is called when removed from background. But if you get some point for deleting app then let me know.

Comment: Can I make any service call in that method,I need to inform my server when he closed the app